# Windows 10 uninstalling my graphics driver and replacing it with a different one

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

Recently, my computer has been uninstalling its current graphics driver and replacing it with that of a different type of graphics card. It goes from AMD Catalyst version 15.7.1 to an AMD Radeon driver (I don't know exactly which as it wont open due to me having the wrong type of hardware for it).

At the moment, I am uninstalling the graphics driver with [this program](http://www.wagnardsoft.com/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-) then running the [AMD Autodetect](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) program, and installing the driver it recommends. However this seems only to be a temporary fix, because it has usually uninstalled the Catalyst driver and replaced it with the Radeon one by the end of the next day (I have reinstalled the driver 5 times this week already).

On [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1140590/opengl-not-working-on-windows/1141245#1141245) from a few months ago, I was told to use the Catalyst driver for the graphics, when in had a problem with OpenGL not working.

**Computer Specs:**

Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64 bit

Processor: Quad core AMD A8-5557M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 2.10 GHz

RAM: 8.00GB (7.19GB Usable)

Display Adapters: AMD Radeon HD 8550G, AMD Radeon R9 M275X

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/986799/117590

Comment: Catalyst is no longer supported & 15.7.1 is over a year old. Latest AMD drivers are Crimson - currently http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064

Comment: @Tetsujin If Crimson is the correct driver, then why is my computer 'defaulting' to Radeon, and being recommended Catalyst by AMD?

Comment: @Bob I'll look into the answer posted on that question

Comment: Radeon is the generic name for almost all recent ATI/AMD cards, it's not the name of the driver.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, thanks, I'll look into the catalyst drivers

Comment: Ahhh - you have a legacy APU, but a currently supported additional GPU, so you actually do need to stick to 15.7.1 The 8550G is no longer supported, but the M275X is - that's why the confusion